# What happens in between planets?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

I was wondering in an area of space where there arent enough planets around it to suck an object in with gravity, does the object just float there? And if it does just float there will other objects eventually gravitate to it or pick it up eventually? This is a question I've asked a few of my physics and science teachers a few times, but none of them have really answered it very clearly in my opinion. Tell me if my question is unclear.

Comment: What answers did you get from your teachers? What was not clear about them? It would be pointless for us to repeat the same answers.

Comment: Gravity has an infinite range, in the Newtonian model. The effects of gravity can be predicted  by a sum of vectors.  In other words, between planets and stars, a mass will always experience pulls from everything around it. How the mass moves depends on how close it is to each planet or star.

Comment: look up "Lagrange points" on wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an object is not close enough to a planet to orbit a planet, it will orbit the Sun.

If an object is not close enough to the Sun (or another star) to orbit it, it will orbit the centre of the Galaxy.

If an object is somewhere in intergalactic space, it will take a very long time before it goes anywhere.

The proper word for "close enough" is the [Hill sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere) or the [Sphere of influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence_(astrodynamics)).